# How to create a "run" command from the Alloy API?

Tags: alloy

I'm trying to run a predicate, `Test1`, from inside the Alloy API. I create a command to run `Test1` in my program like this:

```
Expr predExpr = funcWithName("Test1").call();
Expr factExpr = this.world.getAllReachableFacts();
Command c = new Command(false, curScope, -1, -1, factExpr.and(predExpr));

A4Solution ans = TranslateAlloyToKodkod.execute_command(this.reporter, this.world.getAllReachableSigs(), c, this.options);
```

If I run this in my code, `ans` is satisfiable. However, if run the command `run Test1` in the Alloy GUI it is unsatisfiable. I've taken care to make sure the options I pass into the command are the same as the options in the GUI.

My main question is how do I create the exact command that Alloy is running in my code?

Let me know if there's any other information that would be useful and thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be an idea to visualize the A4Solution (you could use the VizGUI class if i remember correctly). It might just be that the model you specified through the API is different from the one you have in your GUI

Comment: I realized that the first `-1` in the Command constructor should be the scope of the command, edited now. Still, the results I get from running the command generated above vs in the code as `run Test1 for curScope` are different. It seems that the `factExpr` above is adding in something extra. Any idea what it may be?

Comment: No sorry :-(. It's been a long time since last time I used the API ...